# Count or sum values from one multidimensional associative array using another

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

I have two multidimensional associative arrays with identical keys. I need to count/sum specific values in one array based on requirements from the other array.

I have tried nested foreach loops but without being able to acquire the requested result. I have searched the Internet to the best of my abilities without success.

Here is my code that didn't work as requested:

```
foreach ($b as $key => $value) {
  foreach ($a as $skey => $svalue) {
    if ($key == $skey) {
      foreach ($svalue[Season] as $ssvalue) {
        if ($value[Appearance] == $ssvalue) {
          $c[$key]['SeasonAppearances'][] = count($value[Appearance]);
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

1st array (extract) / $a

```
$a = Array ( 
        [Paul] => Array ( 
                [Season] => Array ( 
                        [0] => 2014 
                        [1] => 2015 
                        [2] => 2016 
                        ) 
                ) 
        [John] => Array ( 
                [Season] => Array ( 
                        [0] => 2012 
                        ) 
                ) 
    )
```

2nd array (extract) / $b

```
$b = Array ( 
        [Paul] => Array ( 
                [Appearance] => Array ( 
                            [0] => 2014 
                            [1] => 2014 
                            [2] => 2014 
                            [3] => 2014 
                            [4] => 2014 
                            [5] => 2014 
                            [6] => 2014 
                            [7] => 2014 
                            [8] => 2015 
                            [9] => 2015 
                            [10] => 2015 
                            ) 
                ) 
        [John] => Array ( 
                [Appearance] => Array ( 
                            [0] => 2012 
                            [1] => 2012 
                            [2] => 2012 
                            [3] => 2012 
                            ) 
                ) 
        )
```

Requested result array / $c

```
$c = Array ( 
        [Paul] => Array ( 
            [SeasonCounts] => Array ( 
                        [0] => 8 
                        [1] => 3 
                        [2] => 0 
                        ) 
            ) 
        [John] => Array ( 
            [SeasonCounts] => Array ( 
                        [0] => 4 
                        ) 
            ) 
    )
```

I would like to count the number of appearances in $b matching each person for each season in $a and create the result array. Please notice that Paul have no appearances in 2016.

Comment: Shouldn't `abc` be `Paul` and `def` be `John`?

Comment: And would it not be better if the result array had the Year as the key and not a simple 0,1,2

Comment: Yes my mistake. It's corrected now.

Comment: I think I would like to keep it simple 0,1,2 because $c will be included in another array with similar setup using array_replace_recursive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this should count like you want it

```
$c = array();
$helper = array();
foreach ($b as $key => $value) {

    $c[$key] = array();
    $c[$key]["SeasonCount"] = array();
    $helper[$key] = array();
    foreach ($value["Appearance"] as $key1 => $value1) {

        $position = array_search($value1, $helper[$key]);
        if (false !== $position) {
            $c[$key]["SeasonCount"][$position]++;
        } else {
            $helper[$key][] = $value1;
            $c[$key]["SeasonCount"][] = 1;
        }

    }}
```

Comment: You are new here, so I will explain the point of Stackoverflow.  To post great content, providing working solutions is only the beginning.  Every answer should contain an explanation of how it works, the benefits of the approach, and any additional considerations.  Aim to not only support the OP, but to educate and empower thousands of future researchers.  Remember, these posts are going to last for a long time; try to help as many people as possible.

Answer (score 2):

A condition-less, functional approach: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/KIseX))

```
$season_data = [
    'Paul' => [
        'Season' => [2014, 2015, 2016]
    ],
    'John' => [
        'Season' => [2012]
    ]
];

$appearance_data = [
    'Paul' => [ 
        'Appearance'=> [
            2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2015, 2015, 2015 
        ]
    ],
    'John' => [
        'Appearance' => [
            2012, 2012, 2012, 2012 
        ]
    ]
];

foreach ($season_data as $person => $data) {
    $defaults = array_fill_keys($data['Season'], 0);
    $result[$person]['SeasonCounts'] = array_replace(
        $defaults,
        array_intersect_key(
            array_count_values($appearance_data[$person]['Appearance']),
            $defaults
        )
    );
}
var_export($result);
```

Output:

```
array (
  'Paul' => 
  array (
    'SeasonCounts' => 
    array (
      2014 => 8,
      2015 => 3,
      2016 => 0,
    ),
  ),
  'John' => 
  array (
    'SeasonCounts' => 
    array (
      2012 => 4,
    ),
  ),
)
```

Using functions for this task clarifies the tasks being performed -- making code easily comprehended by future developers.

- For each person, I temporarily store the desired years with a zero value.
- Then I call `array_count_values()` to swiftly generate an array of appearance years and their counts (this is the exact task the function was born to do).
- Then filter the array to only retain the years nominated in the person's season array with `array_intersect_key()`.
- Finally, replace any zeros with their new respective count values via `array_replace()`.

As a slight modification of the above, you could filter *before* counting like this: [Demo](https://3v4l.org/GNEcZ).

Just four function clean, readable function calls per person for your exact desired result.

My result array is designed with associative `SeasonCounts` subarrays because the data is literally associative.  Storing the output with indexed counts loosens the relationship -- this loss is avoided with my approach.

---

Alternatively, you can make iterated filter&count calls for every occurrence of a Season for each person. ([Same result](https://3v4l.org/XeEbT))

```
foreach ($season_data as $person => $data) {
    foreach ($data['Season'] as $year) {
        $result[$person]['SeasonCounts'][$year] = sizeof(
            array_filter(
                $appearance_data[ $person]['Appearance'],
                function($v) use ($year) {
                    return $v == $year;
                })
            );
    }
}
```

---

Finally a functionless, conditional incrementing approach. ([Same result](https://3v4l.org/GLVU4))

```
foreach ($season_data as $person => $data) {
    foreach ($data['Season'] as $year) {
        $result[$person]['SeasonCounts'][$year] = 0;
        foreach ($appearance_data[$person]['Appearance'] as $appearance) {
            if ($appearance == $year) {
                ++$result[$person]['SeasonCounts'][$year];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @SVL just so you can understand the difference between the two answers, my solution will make four function calls per person no matter what.  The other answer will make _n_ array_search calls where _n_ is the total number of appearances across all people.  In this case, that is 15 calls.  Look closer at the other answers output, it doesn't provide the `0` count for 2016.  Please be very careful to award the green tick to correct solutions so that you don't confuse future researchers.  Since you are new, I will explain that you can move the green tick if you choose to - no obligation.